# Adjective or possessive?

Tags: possessives, zero-article, proper-nouns

Consider the following sentence:

`Who is the president of France?`

I want to build a shorter sentence and I don't know if I should use a noun adjective or possessive mark:

`Who is the France's president?`

or

`Who is the France president?`

Replacing `of` by `'s` seems more logic, but the second sentence looks ok to me.

Thus, my questions are:

- Which of these sentences are grammaticaly correct?
- If both are correct, should I prefer one sentence?

Comment: Your first example is fine.  *France's* in your second example is a genitive noun phrase acting as a determiner, so there's no room for the determiner *the*; you should say "Who is France's president?"  In your third example, using *France* as an attributive noun ("Who is the France president?") is grammatical but it probably isn't what you want to do here (for semantic reasons).

Comment: Adding a rather crucial point to what snailboat said: your latter option 
saves a mere three characters, and the former just one (one!). "Who's France's president?" 
saves four, and even "Who's France's president?" would only save six — you have used 
*80 times* as many for this post alone. Talk about [straining at a gnat while swallowing 
a camel](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62814/saving-on-the-parrots-chocolate-is-futile).
Leave it as it was. It was fine. And now it isn't. Do not fix what's not broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you talk about possessiveness, the article is not put.

> **The house** of Tom -*okay*

But...

> **The Tom's** house - *not okay*.

So...

> Who is **the** president of France? -*okay* 
>  Who is France's president? -*okay*.

But...

> Who is **the** France's president? -*not okay*.

As far are *preferring one* is concerned, **"The president of...."** is more common I think.

Comment: Although one might discuss the semantics, a _very_ common option is of course _who's the French president?_.

Comment: The OP wanted to know about "Who is the France president?" as well.  Perhaps you could add a note about that sentence to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Neither make sense.

> Who is the president of France?

makes the most logical sense, but its the one you want to shorten.

> Who is the Frances president?

Is incorrect because of "The", but could be logistically shortened even more as "Who is Frances president?".

> Who is the France president?

Is using the wrong term for French. Can't remember what its called right now but that has it's own term in English. It could also be easily fixed as:

> Who is the *French* president?

Answer (score 0):

"Who is the France president?" is incorrect, but you can say "Who is the French president?"  Still, "Who is the president of France?" is the most colloquial.